# C#/XNA Newbie with a Design question

Tags: c#, design-patterns, xna

I'm trying to design a small game using C# and XNA, before I start I wanted to make sure that this approach makes sense:

Basically, I want to create a GameObject Class that contains all elements that are common with everything I am going to draw on screen, be it a Weapon, Monster, Human, Pickup, etc.

So I was thinking I should create an Abstract Class called GameObject with Properties to set the Texture2D, Vector2 Location, A Draw() Method and a Move() Method.

Also, as I have Humans and Monsters, I could create a base class called Biped or similar and give it an "AttackBehavior" property (Which is a class in itself) so then I can create different attack methods (Humans attack Monsters, Monsters attack Humans). I would use an abstract implementation of the Move() method in my GameObject class so I can override it for items that don't move (Weapons, etc) and give different Move Speeds, patterns, etc to my Humans and Monsters.

So my questions are:

- Does this design pattern make sense? I've been reading Head First Design Patterns and reading about Composing objects (Hence my AttackBehavior object)
- What type of code should I put in my Game1.cs? Should this be the 'View' in the MVC pattern?

Comment: your abstract "GameObject" class is generally called a "Sprite"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the surface, yes the design makes sense ... but in my experience (YMMV of course) I've found that trying to start by designing a deep object hierarchy from the get-go results in decisions that will limit you later. Since every game is unique, I have better results when I just start coding, adding elements to the game, and refactoring as I go. If there are two classes with similar functionality, then I either make them inherit from a common base, or refactor out into a common class which can be re-used. That gives you the best of both worlds.

to your second question, the way that I wholehearted suggest you organize your game is by using the game state management sample:
http://create.msdn.com/en-us/samples/gamestatemanagement

download the sample, and learn it well ... it's a tried and true pattern

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I'll check that pattern out.

I can imagine it's very easy to get bogged down with the details at the very start.

Comment: Beware of creating a GameObject class that tries to represent every possible property or operation that could be done on any game object.  Most game objects will not support all operations.  You are often better with a minimal GameObject class with only properties that are common to all game objects but that supports a GetInterface method to query for interfaces that are supported by only a subset of your game objects.  For instance you could have interfaces for physical objects or damageable objects.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, I don't think that a weapon should ever be in the same class as something that is able to move.

Also try to separate your "model" from your sprites (think MVC for games). It might not always be the best idea to have a base object that both lets behaviour as visual extend. But for a simple game this is the quickest (and maybe) best approach. Really matters what size you're thinking. (Always start small in the beginning).